# How to get specific document data from firebase and return as a string

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a data in firestore like this:
[image]

am trying to get `FCMToken` from a user document
And be able to immediately use it as a string inside a **streambuilder**

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("usersToken")
.doc(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['userId'].toString())
.get();
//I don't know what to do from here on to be able to get it as a string
```

How do I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Please how do i do it and you know a streambuilder can't use await async." But since you're using `get()`, you'll need to use a `FutureBuilder` instead of a `StreamBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('COLLECTION_NAME').document('TEST').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        var userDocument = snapshot.data;
        return new Text(userDocument["property_name"]);
      }
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks but i used `snapshot.data.docs[0]['FCMToken']` to get it